# Arrow function in EC6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am having difficulty understanding arrow function in javascript. I looked up in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
 and found this code.

```js
var res, elements = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

//First
res = elements.map(function(element) {
  return element.length;
});
console.log(res);

//Second
res = elements.map(element => {
  return element.length;
});
console.log(res);

//Third
res = elements.map(({length}) => length);
console.log(res);
```

I get the first and second way just fine, but the third method makes no sense to me.

**First**: I didn't understand what these 2 brackets `()` and `{}` in `({ length })` are.

**Second**: The first word `lenght` also makes no sense. Is it just some random variable?

Anybody willing to shed some light would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), in this case in the parameter list but it works exactly like it does in assignment. You need the outer `()` because when the parameter list of an arrow function is anything other than one simple parameter (like `element`), you have to have `()` around the arrow function's parameter list. Then, within those `()`, the `{length}` indicates destructuring (taking the `length` property from what's passed in).

Comment: The longer form still using destructuring (but assignment this time instead of in the parameter list) would be: `.map(element => { let {length} = element; return length; })`